# Global compiler flags in CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

We are using the -Werror -Wextra -Wall -pedantic compiler flags, and C++11 diaelect. We want to use these for all of our projects. Currently we are setting these to each project by `Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler`.

But this is a project-level setting.

I read lots of questions, i tried lots of things, but i did not found a working solution for setting the flags globally. Is there a way to do this? I am using the latest Eclipse (4.4 Luna), and the latest CDT (8.4).

Answer (score 0):

I am also using eclipse luna.

In top menu : `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Build` -> `Settings`

Select `Discovery` tab, and change the `CDT GCC Built-in settings` (if you use gcc).

Default is like :

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

change to

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}" -Werror -Wextra -Wall -pedantic
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it is not working for me. Please note i am using Windows and MinGW. I set the flags for `CDT GCC Built-in settings` and `CDT GCC Built-in settings MinGW`, too.
But the compiler command is still like this: `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\test.o" "..\\src\\test.cpp"`.

Comment: Are your project settings still active and being used in preference? I know you've said you've changed the project settings already.

Comment: @JohnJefferies I created a new project for testing this.

Comment: AFAIK (I haven't checked it in Luna), the discovery settings are used only to determine the built-in symbols from the compiler in order to correctly parse system headers during indexing. Otherwise, the other flags already present there (`-E -P -v -dD`) wouldn't make any sense.